# Environment for java + scala + lift project in eclipse without maven

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, build-automation, sbt

I'm trying to understand what's the best way to setup a project
that is a mix of java and scala and that will use lift.
Lift is intended to run embedded by jetty in another application.

I'm comfortable to work in Eclipse and also used to how it
works with ant as build tool.
I'm a relatively newbie in both scala and lift and get confused
about the different build tool and how to set up things.
I don't really understand maven and haven't really looked at sbt,
but it seem to be the choice of scala developers, but I'm also
dependent on quite some javacode.

Any suggestions, links, tutorials or else on how to setup
the best environment so I can work comfortably in Eclipse
and also build releases quite easily given my scala/java/lift/jetty 
enrironment?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that if you are comfortable using Ant as a build tool, Maven should be a piece of cake to use instead. It's main advantage is encouraging conforming to conventions rather than lots of configuration meaning that as long as you follow the standards, setup and usage of any most maven projects is a breeze. I strongly recommend that you invest the time to become familiar with this build tool because it will be very valuable experience/knowledge you can continue to use in your Java career.

With Maven aside, if you are convinced that you and the rest of the project's devs will all be using Eclipse, I would recommend using Eclipse's built in project management infrastructure. It uses Ant under the hood so you will be able to leverage you experience to also run/release from the command-line. All you need to do is set up a eclipse Lift project normally and then to add the scala integration, check out [Scala IDE](http://www.scala-ide.org/) for pretty good IDE support of scala development inside of eclipse.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your opinions, I probably need to read up a bit on Maven
before discarding it. Coming form a classic approach of simple
old school makefiles and ant scripts, these tools, like maven
and sbt seem overcomplicated to me and I hate when there is magic involved.

Given that we develop inside Eclipse, is it easy to export a build
tool to make builds off-eclipse? Also, I want to use stuff like 
hudson or similar for long term testing etc., and then I need ways to build and run from commandline.

Any takes on this?

Comment: Maven is definitely worth the effort IMO but I will admit it does do a lot of things for you, a.k.a. "magic". As for eclipse, I have not used it for a couple of years so I can't comment on how to set up builds/releases. I am sure you can find that information out on either the eclipse website or right here on SO. And about using external build tools for CI and testing, anything you can do from a command-line can be executed from Hudson/TeamCity/etc. And for the record, Maven build configurations are automatically supported in both Hudson and TeamCity ;)

Answer (score 1):

[This screencast](http://mgutz.com/2010/03/06/get_started_with_scala_sbt_and_eclipse.html) is what I used to get started.   It starts with a [git repository](http://github.com/mgutz/sbt-console-template) for an SBT template and then adds the [Eclipsify sbt plugin](http://github.com/musk/SbtEclipsify) to make it into an Eclipse project.

Comment: Thanks thats a very good start!

I can of course inside eclipse add java nature etc., but I still want to be able to compile my stuff
also from commandline (sbt). How do I then add java to this in sbt?
Finally how to I add lift to sbt, before or after eclipsifying and how?

Finally do people think this is the best way to handöle such a project, anybody have comments on that?